# How to write a transpose for this input of the records in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
331 QUIZ0000000062  919652503596    2017-07-10 18:54:33.217 NULL    NULL    Falciform ligament  A
332 QUIZ0000000062  919652503596    2017-07-10 18:54:33.217 NULL    NULL    Coronary ligament   B
333 QUIZ0000000062  919652503596    2017-07-10 18:54:33.217 NULL    NULL    Mesentery of the lesser sac C
334 QUIZ0000000062  919652503596    2017-07-10 18:54:33.217 NULL    NULL    Ligamentum teres    D
```

The ouput should be for transpose of question as column with options in each column, like :

```
QuestionCode      A                     B                         C          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIZ0000000062  Falciform ligament Coronary ligament Mesentery of the lesser sac 

       D
----------------
Ligamentum teres
```

Comment: Will there always be four options (A through D), or could you have some more complicated questions... say a matching question with more options.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can accomplish what your looking for by doing some `SELF JOINS`.

```
CREATE TABLE #aa(
    ID INT,
    QuestionCode NVARCHAR(100),
    SomeNumber BIGINT,
    DateColumn DATETIME,
    NullColumn1 INT,
    NullColumn2 INT,
    Answer varchar (100),
    AnswerLetter char
)  

INSERT #aa (ID,QuestionCode,SomeNumber,DateColumn,Answer,AnswerLetter)    
VALUES      
    (331,'QUIZ0000000062',919652503596,'2017-07-10 18:54:33.217','Falciform ligament','A'),
    (332,'QUIZ0000000062',919652503596,'2017-07-10 18:54:33.217','Coronary ligament','B'),
    (333,'QUIZ0000000062',919652503596,'2017-07-10 18:54:33.217','Mesentery of the lesser sac','C'),
    (334,'QUIZ0000000062',919652503596,'2017-07-10 18:54:33.217','Ligamentum teres','D')

SELECT q.QuestionCode,a.Answer 'A',b.Answer 'B',c.Answer 'C',d.Answer 'D'
FROM #aa q
    JOIN #aa a ON q.AnswerLetter = a.AnswerLetter AND a.AnswerLetter = 'A'
    JOIN #aa b ON q.AnswerLetter = a.AnswerLetter AND b.AnswerLetter = 'B'
    JOIN #aa c ON q.AnswerLetter = a.AnswerLetter AND c.AnswerLetter = 'C'
    JOIN #aa d ON q.AnswerLetter = a.AnswerLetter AND d.AnswerLetter = 'D'

DROP TABLE #aa
```

**Results:**

```
+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+
| QuestionCode  |       A            |     B             |           C                 |        D         |
+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+
|QUIZ0000000062 | Falciform ligament | Coronary ligament | Mesentery of the lesser sac | Ligamentum teres |
+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+
```